# Qt 5.2 with MySQL- driver not loaded

Tags: mysql, qt, drivers

**Hello there,**
I’ve downloaded and installed Qt 5.2 32 bit for android, my machine is windows 8 64bit, I also have visual studio 2012 installed, MySQL 5.6.16 32bit is installed.

I’m trying to connect to a MySQL database, but I always get this error

QSqlDatabse: QMYSQL driver not loaded 
QSqlDatabse: available drivers: QSQLIT QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Here is my code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    return a.exec();
}
```

I added the path **C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib** to my PATH environment and to the path in the run panel in Qt Creator.
I’ve known that in Qt 5.2 there is no need to build the driver, anyway I’v tried and built it but with no difference, I don’t know if the built process went well or no.
Any suggestions please because I spent the last two days searching the net for a solution.
**Thanks.**

Comment: Check with dependency walker that the plugin’s dependencies match the libs in MySQL Server 5.6\lib

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld How do I do this I downloaded dependency walker, but I don't know which file to check
here is the files in this PATH C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql
main.cpp,mysql.json,mysql.pro,README

Comment: The plugin DLL, which is something like qmysql.dll in the Qt installation (not the source tree), plugins/ folder

Comment: I found the file qsqlmysql.dll in this path 
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\mingw48_32\plugins\sqldrivers
and I run dependacy walker on it and here is a photo of what I got
http://imageshack.com/a/img197/4814/ek87.JPG

Comment: then make sure libmysql.dll is available and found at runtime (e.g. by adding its location to the PATH).

Comment: Well the path C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib which include the libmysql.dll is already in the system PATH !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was that I downloaded the offline MySQL installer for windows(x86-32bit) the installer is 32bit, but the server combined  with it was (5.6 64bit) looks like there is no 5.6 server 32bit so I installed the 5.5 32bit server instead and it worked.

thanks for the help.